# AWS pullling all the dependencies

Tags: java, aws-sdk

Is there some list available for me to exclude all irrelevant dependencies from aws-sdk?

When I gradle fresh this 
compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.401'

it pulls close to 70 odd dependencies,which is huge.I only need Kinesis from core SDK and Elastic Search which AWS does not provide library for.
For ES we are going to make direct rest call through some kind of client lib.

Question: How do I exclude all irrelevant dependencies.And has AWS segreagted the services by their functionality. I don't understand how pulling alexa as part of doing just Kinesis makes sense

Comment: can you share your gradle or pom file? I just checked my dependency tree, and can't see any extra library. FYI, I am using aws-java-sdk-core, aws-java-sdk-kinesis, aws-java-sdk-sqs and amazon-kinesis-client.

Comment: yes i figured out.Now I  am using these directly aws-java-sdk-core, aws-java-sdk-kinesis, aws-java-sdk-sqs.aws-java-sdk is one which ends up pulling all the dependecies.Thanks for ur answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the AWS SDK BOM to manage the dependencies for you. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/managing-dependencies-with-aws-sdk-for-java-bill-of-materials-module-bom/

For your use case, your pom file would look something like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.10</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kinesis</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```